# Vagrant VM : Bad configuration option: IdentitiesOnly

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I installed the vagrant VM, but when i run:

```
vagrant ssh
```

it display an error of configuration:

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: IdentitiesOnly
```

I checked :

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

it display me:

```
C:\Vagrant\Ubuntu1>vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Vagrant/Ubuntu1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Can you tell me why, knowing that the first time i'm using vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

`IdentitiesOnly` option is in OpenSSH since 2004 (OpenSSH 3.9). If you are using older version, you should certainly update.

Other possibility is to remove the colliding option, since it is not crucial to the functionality.

Comment: the version of ssh is: SSH Secure Shell 3.2.9 (Build 283)
And, what do you mean by the "colliding option".

Comment: The `IdentitiesOnly` is colliding option for you. SSH 3.2 is very old with many possible security problems.